# Obter o Imei no Android usado o Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou precisando o obter um identificador único para o meu app, estou tentando pegar o IMEI do dispositivo e não estou conseguindo, abaixo segue o código que tentei obter o IMEI e ele sempre para no primeiro if que tem o `return "imei error";`

Método para obter o IMEI

```
public String obterImei() {
        String imeinum = "huhu";


        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return "imei error";
        }else{

            imeinum = tm.getDeviceId();

            return imeinum;
        }
    }
```

Chamada do método:

```
   String imei = obterImei();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usei o método abaixo para obter o MAC.
[Crédito](https://www.it-swarm.net/pt/android/obtendo-o-endereco-mac-no-android-6.0/1055238708/)

```
public static String getMacAddr() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                res1.append(String.format("%02X:",b));
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return "02:00:00:00:00:00";
}
```

Comment: É possível pegar o IMEI do Android 10 (Q)?

Comment: cara acho que não

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar assim para poder, recuperar o *IMEI* do dispositivo.

```
/**
 * Returns the unique identifier for the device
 *
 * @return unique identifier for the device
 */
public String getDeviceIMEI() {
    String deviceUniqueIdentifier = null;
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (null != tm) {
        deviceUniqueIdentifier = tm.getDeviceId();
    }
    if (null == deviceUniqueIdentifier || 0 == deviceUniqueIdentifier.length()) {
        deviceUniqueIdentifier = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }
    return deviceUniqueIdentifier;
}
```

Mas não esqueça de colocar no **Manifest.xml**.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Crédito: [How to get the device's IMEI/ESN programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-get-the-devices-imei-esn-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: não deu certo ele pede checkPermission

Comment: Nesse link tem a parte de checagem de permissão se você puder dar uma olhadinha vai ver que lá tem respostas mais completa.